# Dynamic attribute Jquery selector attr('for="*"')

Tags: jquery

Jquery Selector:

```
//left side
$('section.abstract label.gcsubheader')
//right side
$('fieldset.abstract label.formElems')
```

Both Return: (with the class differing, but the `for="*"` remaining the same)

```
<label for=​"design" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Design​</label>​ 
<label for=​"expertise" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Expertise​</label>​
<label for=​"skills" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Skills​</label>​
<label for=​"tools" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Tools​</label>​
<label for=​"projects" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Projects​</label>​
<label for=​"community" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Community​</label>​
<label for=​"interests" class=​"displayHidden formElems">​Interests​</label>​
```

I would like to append to the left selector something similar to the following:

```
.find($('label[for="' + $(this).text().toLowerCase() + '"]'))
```

or

```
var $this = $(this).text().toLowerCase();   //and use the $this in the concatenation:
```

to accomplish selecting elements with `labels for="design"` like the selector `($('label[for="design"]'))`, but by doing it dynamically.   The idea is that I am trying refactoring for the first time, and have very many elements, and when I click on one element, I would like to find itself, and the other one that shares its `label for` string.

I have tried:

```
$('section.abstract label.gcsubheader').click(function () {
     var $this = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
     //left element - hide
     $('section.abstract label.gcsubheader')..find($('label[for="' + $this + '"]')).show();
     //Right Side - show
     $('fieldset.abstract label.formElems').find($('label[for="' + $this + '"]')).show();
}
```

and

```
$('fieldset.abstract label.formElems').find($('label[for="' + $(this).text().toLowerCase() + '"]')).show();
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.   Do I have to allow for another layer of abstraction to grab/define the element's text, or is my syntax wrong, or something else off?   I am hoping to get this, so I can then toggle both left and right's .hidden class, providing a very robust refactoring of the code, maybe something like this?:

```
$('label[for="*"]').click(function () {
   // for each .toggleClass('hidden'); 
}
```

although not quite sure how to write the `*` or `for each` for that either, but I will get there.   You help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `.` before your first `find()` call, as well as an unclosed string literal being passed as an argument to it. Note the closing brackets for both the inside function and the `click` method. You were also using `.show()` for the left element when you probably wanted `.hide()`.

Additionally, it's perfectly fine to append the attribute equals selector to your original selector statement like this (I didn't have your full html so the selector may need to be tweaked a little bit):

```
$('section.abstract label.gcsubheader').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

    //left element - hide
    $('section.abstract label.gcsubheader[for="' + $this + '"]').hide();

    //Right Side - show
    $('fieldset.abstract label.formElems[for="' + $this + '"]').show();
});
```

As for binding to any of your labels, consider using the [has-attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) instead of `for='*'`:

```
$('label[for]').click( /* ... */ );
```